# Restricted thermal expansion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, forces

[image]

Imagine a metal rod of length $l$ with mass $m$. How would it expand upon a temperature difference of $\Delta\vartheta$ with an expansion coefficient of $\alpha$ when there are two forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ action on it ($F_1\neq F_2$). How do the expansions to the right ($\Delta x_2$) and to the left ($\Delta x_1$) behave? Of course $\Delta x_1+\Delta x_2 =\alpha l\Delta\vartheta$, but just I don't know what $\Delta x_1$ and $\Delta x_2$ are. Also there is friction between the rod and the floor with frictional coefficient of $\mu$ where $F_1,F_2<\mu mg$ and $\mu<1$.

I would be delighted, if you helped me.

Comment: If F1 is not equal to F2 the rod is accelerating in one direction or the other.

Comment: I forgot to say that there's also the frictional force which hinders the rod to accelerate @JonCuster

Comment: Suppose there were no forces on the ends...just static friction.  How would you (Felix) assess what would happen as a result of the temperature increase?

Comment: @FelixGelbh Is it necessary to take into account the elastic deformation of the rod?

Comment: What I'm asking (Felix) is what do you think the solution to this problem would look like if the two forces were zero and the rod were glued to the floor (simulating high static friction)?  If you can't answer this question, you, of course, could not attack the problem with the two forces also being present?  Another problem I would try to solve first would be "what would happen if the two different forces were present but there we no temperature increase?"

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'd like to know whether it is possible without taking the elastic deformation into account or at least without being given the young modulus.

Comment: @ChetMiller If it were glued on the floor it would break in my opinion, if the young modulus is very high. But let's limit $\mu$ to being smaller thang one, so it's granted that the rod doesn't break. And concerning the other question of yours, I think that nothing happens, assuming the young modulus is very high and the forces so small that the elastic deformation is negligible. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case where the two forces are not present, but the temperature is increased, if the rod is long enough, the broad center portion of the rod will experience virtually no axial strain and no shear stress at the floor, and the compressive stress in this portion of the rod will be $E\alpha \Delta \theta$ (just as if the entire rod were constrained axially).  Toward each of the two ends of the rod, however, there will be a "boundary layer" region in which the axial stress transitions from this high compressive stress in the center region to zero at the ends.  This transition in stress will be brought about by shear stress at the floor that builds up from zero near the center region to a maximum value at the ends (assuming that the temperature rise is not high enough for the shear stress to exceed the critical value for static friction release).  The axial displacement profile within the rod will vary with distance from the floor, from a value of zero at the floor to a maximum value at the top surface.  So the variation in displacement will be two dimensional near the two edges.  Quantifying this qualitative picture would require solving the stress equilibrium equations in conjunction with the strain-displacement equations and Hooke's law (3D version).  The effective extent of the two edge regions at the two ends of the rod would be expected to be on the order of 2-3 rod thicknesses from each of the ends.